# Elfinder select folder as well as file in standalone popup

Tags: laravel, file-manager, elfinder

I am using elfinder as a file manager in one of my laravel project using barryvdh-elfinder package.
I am using its standalone popup to let the user choose a file from existing files. But I want them to be able to choose folders as well. I can't seem to make it work.

Can anyone help me solve this problem. thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I asked the [same question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045155/how-to-show-a-specific-folder-when-the-interface-opens-in-elfinder), and in Elfinder's forums without success.

Comment: I think your question is entirely different. Have you tried its standalone popup? You can choose a file from elfinder and then the file name is returned in a form input. I want to be able to choose a folder as well.

Comment: You're right, sorry. Did you see [this documentation](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-configuration-options#commandsoptions)? Try setting `folders: true`.

Comment: Wow. It worked perfectly !! that's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As guided by [Tiago A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2546416/tiago-a) ( thanks to him :) )we can use `folder : true` in `commandsOptions` while initializing elfinder like this:

```
$('#elfinder').elfinder({
            // set your elFinder options here
            customData: {
                _token: '<?= csrf_token() ?>'
            },
            url: '<?= URL::action('Barryvdh\Elfinder\ElfinderController@showConnector') ?>',  // connector URL
            dialog: {width: 900, modal: true, title: 'Select a file'},
            resizable: false,
            commandsOptions: {
                getfile: {
                    oncomplete: 'destroy',
                    folders  : true
                }
            },
            getFileCallback: function (file) {
                window.parent.processSelectedFile(file.path, '<?= $input_id?>');
                parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
            }
        }).elfinder('instance');
```